# Laravel Request validation 404 when data is invalid

Tags: laravel, validation

I have trouble with Request validation in Laravel, when request data pass validation everything is ok but then data is invalid server response with 404

UserRequest

```
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

public function rules()
{
    return [
         'name' => 'sometimes|required|unique:users,Name|min:5|max:30'
    ];
}
```

UserController

```
public function update(UserRequest $request, $id)
{
    $token = JWTAuth::getToken();
    $tokenData = JWTAuth::getPayload($token)->toArray();
    if ($request->name != null) {
        if (User::where('id', $tokenData['idUser'])->update(['Name' => $request->name])) {
            $status = true;
        } else {
            $status = false;
        }
    }

    return response()->json(['status' => $status]);
}
```

Comment: please provide your controller's method code

Comment: check your routing on routes/web.php

Comment: im not using web routes, file is clear

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
public function update(UserRequest $request, $id)
{
    $token = JWTAuth::getToken();
    $tokenData = JWTAuth::getPayload($token)->toArray();
    $validated = $request->validated();
    if ($validated) {
        if (User::where('id', $tokenData['idUser'])->update(['Name' => $request->name])) {
            $status = true;
        } else {
            $status = false;
        }
        return response()->json(['status' => $status]);
    }
    else {
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validated);
     }        
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: i would like to response error as JSON, i do : else
            return response()->json(['status' => false, 'error' => $validated]); -- redirects me to '/'. Some middleware is executing? (Laravel 5.8)

Comment: Please provide your code related to this action like from where this method calls and your middleware and routes related to this action